# Firebase is free to use for Unity or not?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

i want to use Firebase in my Augmented Reality application.so 
Kindly someone tell me that Firebase is free for Unity or not?

Comment: Yes, It is free I used it in Unity with oculus.

Comment: If you have questions about the pricing for Firebase services, please address those directly to Firebase support.  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack overflow. Questions that do not show any research effort are expected to be downvoted. Please see the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for advice on how to write a good question.

Answer (score 1):

Most products in Firebase are either completely free, or have a free tier to get you started, but please check the [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) for the product(s) you're interested in using.

The pricing is unrelated to what platform you use Firebase on/from. So if the product you want to use is free or has a free tier, that also applies when you use it from Unity.